# how to write sql condition with same table colums

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `fee_category`

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+
| fee_cat_id | fee_cat_name | parent_id |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
|          1 | days scholar |         0 |
|          2 | tuition      |         1 |
|          3 | exam         |         1 |
|          4 | bus          |         1 |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I want to get based on parent_id fee_type as follows

if `parent_id=1`

then

`feetype=days scholar`

I have tried as below

```
SELECT fee_cat_id
     , fee_cat_name
     , fee_cat_name IN 
         ( select fee_cat_name  
             from fee_category  
            where parent_id !=0
         ) fee_type 
 from fee_category;
```

My output looks like this

```
+------------+--------------+----------+
| fee_cat_id | fee_cat_name | fee_type |
+------------+--------------+----------+
|          1 | days scholar |        0 |
|          2 | tuition      |        1 |
|          3 | exam         |        1 |
|          4 | bus          |        1 |
+------------+--------------+----------+
```

I want output as follows

```
+------------+--------------+----------  +
| fee_cat_id | fee_cat_name | fee_type   |
+------------+--------------+----------  +
|          1 | days scholar |  none      |
|          2 | tuition      |days scholar|
|          3 | exam         |days scholar|
|          4 | bus          |days scholar|
+------------+--------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subquery in `select` list to achieve that:

```
select fee_cat_id,
       fee_cat_name,
       coalesce((select fee_cat_name from fee_category where fee_cat_id = FC.parent_id), 'none') fee_type
from fee_category FC
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c37d8/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can alias the table names.

```
SELECT a.fee_cat_id, a.fee_cat_name, COALESCE(b.fee_cat_name, 'NONE') as fee_type 
FROM fee_category a
LEFT OUTER JOIN fee_category b
ON a.fee_type = b.fee_cat_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this result with a LEFT JOIN of the table to itself to match a parent_id with a fee_cat_name:

```
SELECT fc1.fee_cat_id, fc1.fee_cat_name, IFNULL(fc2.fee_cat_name, 'none') AS fee_type
FROM fee_category fc1
LEFT JOIN fee_category fc2
ON fc2.fee_cat_id = fc1.parent_id
ORDER BY fc1.fee_cat_id
```

Output:

```
fee_cat_id  fee_cat_name    fee_type
1           days scholar    none
2           tuition         days scholar
3           exam            days scholar
4           bus             days scholar
```